Fixed effects vs. dummy variables in cross sectional data?
In panel data regression the term "fixed effects" is often used.
In cross sectional data regression the term "dummy variables" is often used.
Can I apply the concept of "fixed effects" from panel data to "cross sectional data". How would it be different to "dummy variables"?
I was not able grasp the answers given here Can we include fixed effects in cross sectional data? or here Can I use the fixed effects model on cross-sectional data?

The term "fixed effects" causes a lot of confusion. You can resolve this confusion by writing out your models in matrix form and seeing if there are differences.

This is just a question of terminology. In my experience, we call it fixed effects when we add dummy variables to control for unobserved effects on the level the outcome is measured.
Think about a regression to model the income of an individual i in a given year t. If we now include a dummy for each (but one) individual we call this unit fixed effects, and if we include a dummy for each (but one) period, we call this time fixed effects. However, instead of using unit fixed effects, we could also include a dummy for the gender. Now, some people might still call this gender fixed effects but most people will not.
To answer whether we can apply fixed effects to cross sectional data, let's stay with the example above and assume that we collect the income for a cross section of individuals at a given point in time. We could now of course include a gender dummy in our regression - within each gender group there would be variation of the outcome. However, we cannot include unit fixed effects because we observe each unit only once. Including unit fixed effects would therefore yield an R-squared of 100% and no variation left to analyze.

So from a terminology point of view, I could add add a "group fixed effect" (like gender or country dummy), but not a "unit fixed effect" or "time fixed effect" to a cross sectional data regression?

Yes. Think of your data as being made up of different cells. If we include gender fixed effects, we conduct the rest of our analysis within each gender cell. However, as we will most likely have multiple individuals per (male and female) gender cell, we can still estimate effects. If we include individual fixed effects, we conduct our analysis within each individual cell. But: We only have one observation per individual - we are left with no variation that we can analyze.
